# Moodle web service script failing to enrol user

Tags: rest, moodle

I am attempting to add a user via Moodle's REST API, and then take that user and enroll them in a course using the following Ruby script (with line breaks for readability):

```
require 'httparty'
# Credentials
ws_url      = 'https://subdomain.domain.com/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken='
token       = '123abc456def7890ghijklmnop123rst'
ws_function_create  = 'core_user_create_users'
ws_function_enrol   = 'enrol_manual_enrol_users'
rest_format = 'json'


user_data = "users[0][username]=test_user&users[0][auth]=googleoauth2
            &users[0][password]=Password01!&users[0][firstname]=Test
            &users[0][lastname]=User&users[0][email]=test@example.com
            &users[0][idnumber]=000001"

user_response = HTTParty.post(ws_url + token 
                              + '&wsfunction=' + ws_function_create 
                              + '&moodlewsrestformat=' + rest_format
                             , :body => user_data )
puts user_response.parsed_response


enrol_data = "enrolments[0][roleid]=5
             &enrolments[0][userid]=#{user_response.parsed_response[0]['id']}
             &enrolments[0][courseid]=2"

enrol_response = HTTParty.post(ws_url + token 
                               + '&wsfunction=' + ws_function_enrol 
                               + '&moodlewsrestformat=' + rest_format
                              , :body => enrol_data )
puts enrol_response
```

Running this code results in the following output:

```
{"id"=>1411, "username"=>"test_user"}

{"exception"=>"moodle_exception", "errorcode"=>"wsnoinstance", 
 "message"=>"Manual enrolment plugin instance doesn't exist or is disabled for the course (id = {$a->courseid})"}
```

The user add is working fine -- I can see them when I go to the Moodle site, and so I think the web services API is set up correctly. Setting up the API, I created an 'External Service' to which I added two functions, `core_user_create_users` and `enrol_manual_enrol_users`, and the 'API_user' role (which the web_services user is assigned to) is allowed to enrol users, use the REST API, and create users.

Moreover, if I try to do the post without the `enrolments[0][roleid]=5` (which I had previously had an issue with), I get back `{"exception"=>"invalid_parameter_exception", "errorcode"=>"invalidparameter", "message"=>"Invalid parameter value detected"}`, so it looks like I'm getting through with my current error -- I just don't know how to fix.

Moodle documentation appears to vary between wildly out-dated to generally non-existent (or I'm terrible at Google), was hoping someone here might have an idea how to solve.

Comment: Anything here? https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=181591

Comment: There is a little there, but that was more of a database migration issue, whereas mine was mixing up which course I had enabled 'Manual enrolments' on and which I actually was trying to assign. Thanks for the lead all the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this error is tied to a particular courses user enrollment methods settings. If you are getting this error, go to the course's page, and then under *Course Administration > Users > Enrolment methods* (not 'Manual enrolments', which is a sub-category), check to ensure that 'Manual enrolments is enabled (click the eye with a slash through it to turn on).